# iOS: using GCD with Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

at the heart of it, my app will ask the user for a bunch of numbers, store them via core data, and then my app is responsible for showing the user the average of all these numbers.

So what I figure I should do is that after the user inputs a new number, I could fire up a new thread, fetch all the objects in a `NSFetchDescription` instance and call it on my `NSManagedObjectContext`, do the proper calculations, and then update the UI on the main thread.

I'm aware that the rule for concurrency in Core Data is one thread per `NSManagedObjectContext` instance so what I want to know is, do you I think can what I just described without having my app explode 5 months down the line? I just don't think it's necessary to instantiate a whole a new context just to do some measly calculations...

Comment: I like Core Data but if all you're saving is "a bunch of numbers" it might be the wrong tool...especially if you aren't doing anything with them except fetch all (and store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you have described, why not just store the numbers as they are entered into a `CoreData` model and also into an `NSMutableArray`?  It seems as though you are storing these for future retrieval in case someone needs to look at (and maybe modify) a previous calculation.  Under that scenario, there is no need to do a fetch after a current set of numbers is entered.  Just use a mutable array and populate it with all the numbers for the current calculation.  As a number is entered, save it to the model AND to the array.  When the user is ready to see the average, do the math on the numbers in the already populated array.  If the user wants to modify a previous calculation, retrieve those numbers into an array and work from there.

Bottom line is that you shouldn't need to work with multiple threads and merging `Context`s unless you are populating a model from a large data set (like initial seeding of a phonebook, etc).  Modifying a `Context` and calling save on that context is a very fast thing for such a small change as you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you may want to do some testing, especially in regard to the size of the data set.  if it is pretty small, the sqlite calls are pretty fast so you may get away with doing in on the main queue.  But if it is going to take some time, then it would be wise to get it off the main thread.

Apple introduced the concept of parent and child managed object contexts in 2011 to make using MO contexts on different threads easier.  you may want to check out the WWDC videos on Core Data.

You can use NSExpression with you fetch to get really high performance functions like min, max, average, etc.  here is a good link.  There are examples on SO

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/01/19/core-data-queries-using-expressions.html

Good luck!